# Deferring click return with Promise?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, promise

Is it possible to defer a click response using the [Jquery differed object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) structure?

So I've got a click event that fires and calls a long(ish) running process, deferred process. I want to return from the click only when the deferred process has finished, i.e.

```
$('form .modalPopupSearch').click(function (e) {
     //return once the dialogopen event is complete and not before!
     $("#divSearching").dialog('open');

});
```

I thought just adding `promise()` to this **might** do it:

```
$('form .modalPopupSearch').click(function (e) {
     //return once the dialogopen event is complete and not before!
     $("#divSearching").dialog('open');

}).promise();
```

but it doesn't. Is this even possible or does it just not hook up this way?

Comment: No, you can't. you have to return immediately or not at all. You can however store a reference to a promise object in a variable available outside of the click event, then resolve it when the dialog is closed. Note however it will only resolve once, so it would be pretty useless if said event can happen more than once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the main points of asynchronous mechanisms like `Deferred` and `Promise` is **not** to hold up execution of the main JavaScript thread.

No, you can't make completion of a `click` handler wait until a jQuery UI `dialog` has been closed. Your code **does** wait for the call to `dialog` to return (of course), but naturally, that call just *opens* the dialog.

Instead, allow the handler to complete (perhaps stopping the event's propagation and/or the default action) and use the dialog's callback to trigger whatever follow-on action you want to perform.

Comment: Damn it that's what I thought. I have tried the approach you mentioned, but this is breaking some automated testing, as it thinks the click has returned but does not wait for the "follow on script" to complete. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Liam: Your automated test tool should have a feature to wait a moment. Selenium has [`pause`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#pause), for instance.

Comment: yes it does, but the tester says this will take too long to implement. :(

Comment: @Liam: Nice. :-) Well, it's an incredibly common pattern, I think the tester is just going to have to cope. :-)